# Renaming files with Excel VBA - GrantAccessToMultipleFiles

Tags: excel, vba, macos, file, excel-2016

I got a script that works well on Win 10 with Excel 2016. I use it for renaming/numbering files depending to an Excel sheet.

But on Mac I have to confirm the access for each file. As I have over 3000 file to numbered, that's impossible. It has something to do with Macs sandboxing. GrantAccessToMultipleFiles is the keyword.
Can anyone help me to complete this script, that I don't have to confirm every file renaming?

```
sub Test() 
iPath = "c:temp" 
lr = cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row 
for i = 1 to lr 
    name iPath & cells(i,"A") as iPath & Format(i, "0###") & " " & cells(i,"A") 
next i 
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With my experience using Linux I can figure that the problem is folder permissions.
Verify your permissions or read this article (Step 5).

> https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3353